# Can I use clang for parsing C code even though I must use RTTI on my own source code?

Tags: c++, parsing, clang

I'm writing a C++ program where I need to be able to parse C code into an AST, perform some operations on it, and then convert it back to a string representation. In almost all similar questions I've read, the answer is "use clang".

However, according to http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html, the flag `-fno-rtti` must apparently be provided when compiling code which uses clang, but I'm using features such as virtual functions and down-casting objects using `dynamic_cast` in my own code. Is there still a way of using clang, or do I need to resort to another library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang *itself* must be compiled with `-fno-rtti`, but I don't believe there's any requirement for `-fno-rtti` when you're using clang to compile (or just build an AST from) other code.

Answer (score 0):

Either recompile Clang with RTTI enabled, or build it as a shared library (though this one I'm not entirely sure about).